# Database design and query for a aviation training center

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I work for a company that rents sessions in aircraft simulators for clients. Before getting in the simulator, pilots (the clients) must have a valid formation for the simulator he will pilot. A valid formation is a formation sucessfully passed by the pilot and not expired (so we have to store the acquisition date and the expiration date).

### 1. Is my entity-relationship model correct ?

*Entities :*

- **Pilot** : *pilot_id*, first_name, last_name, other identity fields...
- **Simulator** : *simulator_id*, name

*Relationships :*

- (0,n) **Pilots** *are trained for* (0,n) **Simulators** :

Copy paste this code at http://mocodo.wingi.net/ to visually see it :

```
DATE: _acquisition_date, _expiration_date

PILOT: id, first_name, last_name
is Trained For, 0n PILOT, 0n SIMULATOR, 0n DATE
SIMULATOR: id, name
```

Don't forget to click on the 'Refresh' icon to see the result, just above

### 2. Is the corresponding relationnal model correct ?

**PILOT** ([*id*], first_name, last_name, ...) 
**is Trained For** ([*pilot_id, simulator_id, acquisition_date, expiration_date*]) 
**SIMULATOR** ([*id*], name)

Where *pilot_id* refers to ... blablabla. 
Square brackets defines the primary keys of each entity.

### 3. How can I answer to theses questions ?

- *Who are the pilots that can't go in the simulator in which they passed a formation ?*
- *Who are the pilots that will be inapt to go in the simulator in which they passed a formation in x month(s), without counting those who are already inapt ?*

The output that I'm waiting for looks like this :

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                Inapt pilots                    |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| First name | Last name       | Simulator       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| John       | Doe             | Falcon 7X       |
| John       | Doe             | Embraer ERJ 140 |
| Foo        | Bar             | Falcon 20       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Giving for each inapt pilot the simulator in which he can't go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a comment: You don't need expiration date in the `IS_TRAINED_FOR` table.  Pilot and simulator ID plus acquisition date are enough to be unique.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes your data model is usable for the stated purpose.
2. Apart from my comment above, your table definitions are fine.
3. The queries that you are asking for look something like this:

```html
-- Get pilots that are no longer qualified for a simulator that they
-- have previously qualified for...
select distinct
  P.first_name
, P.last_name
, S.name
from PILOT P
  inner join IS_TRAINED_FOR T
on P.id = T.pilot_id
  inner join SIMULATOR S
on T.simulator_id = S.id
where NOT EXISTS (select Q.acquisition_date
              from IS_TRAINED_FOR Q
              where Q.acquisition_date <= NOW()
                and Q.expiration_date >= NOW()
                and Q.pilot_id = T.pilot_id
                and Q.simulator_id = T.simulator_id)
```

Because the above query uses inner joins, only pilots who have once been qualified for a simulator will be show, but because of the WHERE clause, they will only be shown if their qualification is expired.

Note that the correlated subquery is used because simply saying something like the expiration date is less than NOW() will fail if the pilot had a qualification that expired, but was later renewed (and is still valid).

To see who will be disqualified in X months, just add X months to NOW() in the above query like so:  (For this example, assume 4 months...)

`DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 MONTH)`

To see who will be disqualified between now and x months from now, use this query:

```html
-- Get pilots whose qualifications will be expiring for a simulator that they
-- are currently qualified for...
select distinct
  P.first_name
, P.last_name
, S.name
from PILOT P
  inner join IS_TRAINED_FOR T
on P.id = T.pilot_id
  inner join SIMULATOR S
on T.simulator_id = S.id
where NOT EXISTS (select Q.acquisition_date
              from IS_TRAINED_FOR Q
              where Q.acquisition_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
                and Q.expiration_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
                and Q.pilot_id = T.pilot_id
                and Q.simulator_id = T.simulator_id)
  and T.acquisition_date <= NOW()
  and T.expiration_date >= NOW()
  and T.expiration_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 MONTH
```

This second query shows pilots who are not qualified in 4 months (for example) AND they are qualified right now.

Comment: Don't we have to add a `and Q.id = F.id` clause in the `NOT EXISTS` ?

Comment: @palra - Quite right.  Haste makes waste!  I've fixed the snippet.

Comment: I just realized that I misstated my second question, I just corrected it. I think I have to take your method, `SELECT ... acquisition_date <= DATE_ADD(...` and substract it with `MINUS` to `SELECT ... acquisition_date <= NOW()` then. Is that correct ?

Comment: @palra, I want to make sure I understand what you want for your second query.  Are you looking for a list of people whose qualification expires between now and a specific date in the future (_x_ months from now)?

Comment: The solution given here returns me the qualifications expiring in *x* months and after. I want the qualifications that expire between now and *x* months. Does the condition `acquisition <= NOW() AND expiration >= DATE_ADD(...)` means that ?

Comment: @palra - You need to say that the expiration is after now, but before 4 months from now.  I've edited the second query to account for this.